# stream is closed and Could not find acceptable representation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openfeign

i'm consuming a Api witch is returning pdf as
ResponseEntity but it is not working at my api

i'm trying to get de file coming from the external api and provide it at my endpoint.

**# External Api FeignClient class**

```
@FeignClient(value = "esatCalculoFeignClient", url = "${api.url.esat}")
public interface EsatCalculoFeignClient {

    @PostMapping("/pedido/gerar")
    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> gerarPdfDamEsat(@Validated @RequestBody EsatCalculoTaxasRequestDto dto);

}
```

**My service method**

```
//geração de DAM
public InputStreamResource solicitaDamEsat(SolicitacaDamRequestDto dto) throws BusinessException, IOException {
    FormSolicitacaoAlvara entity = this.buscaEntidadePorProtocolo(dto.getProtocolo());
    EsatCalculoTaxasRequestDto esatRequestDamDto = EsatCalculoTaxasRequestDto.toEsatDto(entity,dto.getIdMeioDePagamento(), dto.getQtdParcelas(), "123teste");
    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> file = esatCalculoFeignClient
            .gerarPdfDamEsat(esatRequestDamDto);

        InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(file.getBody().getInputStream());
        return isr;

 
}
```

**my endpoint**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imprimir",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> gerarDam(SolicitacaDamRequestDto dto) throws BusinessException, IOException {
    InputStreamResource file = service.solicitaDamEsat(dto);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .contentLength(file.contentLength())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment: filename="+file.getFilename())
            .body(file);
}
```

**and stackTrace**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKdC.png)

i'm trying to get de file coming from the external api and provide it at my endpoint.

Comment: Try reading the stream directly inside the controller.

Comment: Try with resources one of the best way to communicate with files and resources. So try once try with resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace InputStreamResouce with byte[] in Feign

```
@FeignClient(value = "esatCalculoFeignClient", url = "${api.url.esat}")
public interface EsatCalculoFeignClient {
    
    @PostMapping("/pedido/gerar")
    byte[] gerarPdfDamEsat(@Validated @RequestBody EsatCalculoTaxasRequestDto dto);

}
```

and convert byte[] to InputStreamResource again in service

```
InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte));
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment: filename=file.pdf")
                        .body(isr);
```